# Water pooling in the front yard

Tags: drainage

just bought a home and I'm finding that if it rains heavily, water is pooling around the front yard. Specifically in the two places shows in the images:

[image]

[image]

How can I fix them? I've gutters installed as well, I am thinking this is from a downspout since I see leaves etc.,

I am also really worried about the potential foundation issues from poor drainage.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have a basement below grade?

Comment: no basement, this is  a central Texas home with no basement.

Comment: Your subsoil seems to contain too much clayey/silty fines. You should try to locate the low point in the yard, and dig trenches toward the low point. The trench shall be about 18" wide (or the wall to the edge walkway), and 18" deep (or just level with the bottom of the footing for the wall). It should be filled with coarse/sandy materials that will facilitate the water flow and drain away from the house.

Comment: can you share a zoomed out pic of the front yard and house? we need to see how the water gets there, not just where it gets.

Comment: Thanks, the water gets there when it heavily rains from: 
a) Gutter overflow
b) Rain from roof intersection, that the gutter doesn't catch

Comment: I found roof gutters useless in E TX , unless cleaned about 4 times a year. I left way too many trees when we built.

Comment: you need to fix up the gutters first, then tackle the overflow if it's still a problem. And if the overflow is still a problem, it's a really big/serious problem to fix compared to gutter work or extending downspouts.  Are your gutters clean? Looks like some dirt splashed on the wall from an overflowing gutter... Gutters are one of the most important parts of your house to maintain, and cause a lot of downstream issue when neglected.

Answer (score 1):

No problem for your foundation but you want to move that water away from your house.

A small French drain system can move the water away that is trapped if you have a slope to the road or a way to move it away.

Even on a fairly flat lot most homes are higher than the street running a small French drain away from the home and allowing the water to then continue has worked for me in high clay where there was not much slope but we needed to drain the water from under the house. Using a trench that is backfilled with gravel.
The water flowed down the gravel bed away from the house.